# System.ArgumentException: Invalid postback or callback argument

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, postback

> Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using  in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code-generated (Java)Script contains XML or HTML markup, which is not allowed by ASP.NET built-in XSS validation.

Comment: it is caused by a checkbox, when i click a checkbox and then a button , it fires that error.. How can i avoid it? :(

Comment: @With: Check all code making PostBack. For instance, comment out everything, and then uncomment it back part by part to found what exactly code cause the error.

Comment: i did that with the debugging. With the checkbox not touched..that error doesnt exist. With that checkbox checked and when i click the button..the exception is thrown.. So the only cause is the checkbox

Comment: How can i cancel the checkbox from persisting between the postbacks?

Comment: @With: Please post your markup.  You can remove the most part of exception message, because it makes no sense. Keep just the first paragraph.